# Accessing UIButton via accessibility identifier in cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

How can I access the `Button` which is present in the `Cell` with its accessibility

```
Setting button's accessibility identifier in some method
```

Now I need to access that button which is present inside the cell from its accessibility identifier which was set in step 1 above

I can set tag and access item via tag but can't find identifier method

Comment: What is the context? Why you need to do so? May be we can suggest other alternates.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using delegates

```
class protocol ButtonCellDelegate: class {
    func didPressButtonInCellAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath)

}
```

You should add something like this in your cell class code

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: ButtonCellDelegate?
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    ...
   @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.didPressButtonInCellAt(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

And the implementation itself is:

```
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController, ButtonCellDelegate {

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        ...

    }

    func didPressButtonInCellAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Things you want to do, if a button is pressed
    }

}
```

But if you still want to use tags, you can pass them using `sender`

```
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController {

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
        ...

    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
         let row = sender.tag
         //Things you want to do, if a button is pressed
    }
}
```

Using delegeates is more robust way to deal with such problems, because it would be easy to handle multisection table views and easier to maintain.

If your buttons are created programmatically, you can add action like this:

```
    //YourCell
override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()
         let button = UIButton() //replace with your initialization
         button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.didPressButtonInCellAt(indexPath)
        }
    }
```

if you still want to use tags, you just need to use `addTarget` in `viewDidLoad` and that's it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems understandable but i forgot to mention one thing. The buttons are being added programmatically. What you suggest in this scenario.